# Graphic Glitch on Startup

Tags: error, windows

Blender was working fine a few days ago, but suddenly starting Blender up yields a screen like *this.*
[image: Screenshot of Blender on my system with its new glitch, the startup screen - for some reason - looks like the original image was wrung up into a twisted version of itself, diagonally skewed pieces of the view are stacked vertically within the window.]

For some reason, the glitch doesn't occur when Blender is left free-floating: if I set it to fill the screen or either half of the screen, the glitch happens again. I can't get into system preferences or anything, either, because any pop-up from Blender has the same problem but irreversibly.

I don't know what changed. The only *marginal* thing I could think of is I installed a new library to my Anaconda IDE for Python, but I have the zipped Blender: they each have their own bundled version of Python.

I have a Windows 10 64-bit O.S., if that helps. But again, I don't know why this glitch is happening *now* when Blender was fine *just a couple days ago.* I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Blender, but it doesn't help...

**Edit:** I have tried downloading a fresh copy from Blender's website; I've tried ZIP bundle AND msi executable downloads; I've tried multiple versions of Blender; and I have tried x32 vs x64 variants of each version. The glitch has persisted throughout.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a fresh copy?

Comment: @ViplavPrakash yes; in re-installing Blender, I downloaded a fresh copy from Blender's website itself. I even tried a more recent version of Blender, yet the glitch still happened.

Answer (score 2):

everyone!

I'm the same person as the asker - had to make a new account because Stack Exchange said I hadn't used their email to confirm my email address (because I never *got one*).

I'm not sure why it was screwed up to begin with, but Blender works on my system now. I updated the drivers of my Display Adapters in the Device Manager.

Comment: This also solved my problem. It's definitely a display adapter issue or something to do with the graphics card independent of Blender because I had the same issue for Photoshop as well.

Comment: @AJD. I'm glad it helped! Weird that this sort of thing is affecting Creative Cloud as well... I wonder what makes them so similar.